# Periodic Axes class in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, projection

I have a collection of latitude/longitude points that straddle the longitude=0 line. I'd like to plot these using a matplotlib Axes class that "wraps" the horizontal dimension such that, when looking towards l=360, points at l=1 are plotted at the equivalent of l=361. Ideally, I'd also like something that defines the pan/zoom actions so I can use the plot interactively.

I know that it is possible to [define custom projections in matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/custom_projection_example.html), but I haven't found the equivalent of a Cylindrical projection that implements all of this functionality. I'd rather not use `basemap`. Does anyone know if something like this exists somewhere?

Comment: I have with a similar problem ( [0,2\pi] data]) and deal with it by pre-processing the data to be in the range I want, but an axes class that does in automagically would be great.

Comment: Do you not want to use ``basemap`` because it doesn't do what you want, or for some other reason?

Comment: I'm looking for something that depends only on matplotlib core, and not an external toolkit like basemap

Comment: This functionality would be really useful!

Comment: Is it such a bad idea to use polar coordinates? Does your coordinate system have to be carthesian?

Answer (score 2):

You can get exactly what you are asking for by modifying the mathplotlib exapmle - [api example code: custom_projection_example.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/custom_projection_example.html) you just need to decide if you would like a spherical representation or cylindrical - if the latter then you may find more useful code in the [custom_scale_example.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/custom_scale_example.html) which also includes panning and zooming but in the example deliberatly limits the data to +-90 degrees - you will need to wrap instead.

[image: Spherical Plot] [image]

Comment: Addressed the lack of panning and zooming by pointing out another example that is specific to cylindrical projection and includes panning and zooming.

Comment: These are nice references, but still not the solution I'm looking for. Like you say, the code in custom_scale_example manually wraps the data to -180->+180. The question asks whether it's possible to set up MPL projections such that data in a range like [0, 360] can be auto-wrapped on the fly, depending on the view window (think google.com/maps at the widest zoom setting)

Comment: @ChrisB Correction custom_scale explicitly limits the data to -85..+85 degrees.  The answer is Yes it is possible to do - I have to actually get on with some paying work but __you__ _should_ be able to adapt one of the examples above - with help from the other one - in a reasonably short time, (I would estimate 2-3 hours modifying and testing).

Comment: Although no full-blown jackpot, it is worth the bounty.

Comment: Thank-you - I may revisit when I have some time on my hands.